# Mount vue after a worker is ready

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite, msw

I am using [msw.js](https://mswjs.io) as request mocking library.

However, some requests are triggered on development before the msw web worker is ready. I can be sure of because the first requests fail. I retry them in the UI with the DevTools and it works as expected.

Here my `main.ts`:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { router } from './routes'
import { pinia } from './pinia.setup'

import App from './App.vue'

import { onUnhandledRequest } from './mocks/browser'

const prepareWorkers = async () => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    const { worker } = await import('./mocks/browser')
    await worker.start({
      onUnhandledRequest
    })
  }
  return Promise.resolve()
}

prepareWorkers().then(() => {
  const app = createApp(App)

  app.use(pinia)
  app.use(router)
  app.mount('#app')
})
```

As you can see, I am already following the [deffered mounting recommandations](https://mswjs.io/docs/recipes/deferred-mounting) without success and I am running out of idea.

I am using vite and it may also be something related to it as all files are downloaded from the vite dev server.
Also the requests are triggered in a composable, outside of the function. As example:

```js
// useMyStatefulComposable.ts

// instantiate it once for multiple composable instances
const allResquests = Promise.allSettled(urls.map(url => fetch(u)))

export const useMyStatefulComposable = () => {
  // using the allRequests result inside the composable

  return { myReactiveData }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That the requests are instantly done in useMyStatefulComposable.ts without waiting for the application to be initialized is a mistake that needs to be fixed. If they should be done once, this needs to be done lazily:

```
let allRequests;

export const useMyStatefulComposable = () => {
  if (!allRequests) {
    allRequests = Promise.allSettled(urls.map(url => fetch(u)))
  }
  ...

  return { myReactiveData }
}
```

Considering that these are the results of `allRequests` that need to be processed in `useMyStatefulComposable`, the promises possibly need to be chained inside `if (!allRequests)` either.

Comment: This is exactly how I got my workaround some time later.